# Getting 100 longest movie titles in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, max

I am reading data from a `tsv` file, which has *movie titles*. I have stored all the *titles* and their *lengths* as a *key value pair* in my `Counter` object `counter`:

```
with open(sys.argv[1], encoding="utf-8") as tsv_file:
csv_reader = csv.reader(tsv_file, delimiter="\t")

counter = Counter()

for entry in csv_reader:

    title = entry[1]
    counter [title] += len(title)
```

I know how to use the `.most_common()` method but now I want to display the top 100 longest titles from `counter.values()`. I probably could use a trivial method for this but I can't seem to find one, please help me?

Comment: Put all the titles in a list, sort the list by length of the titles, slice the first 100…

Comment: You could also use `heapq.nlargest` function

Comment: @deceze I have put the titles in a list, could you please confirm if this is how you sort by length  `for entry in sorted(titleList, key=len(entry)):` . (My file is large so it'll take too long to test if this works right now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract all titles in a list, and then choose the first 100 elements after sorting the list by length of title

```
#List of titles
titles = [entry[1] for entry in csv_reader]

#Sort the titles by length of string, and get first 100 elements
result = sorted(titles, key=len)[:100]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to using the counter you can write

```
counter.most_common(100)
```

which gives you a sorted list of tuples (title, length).
I'd also write

```
counter[title] = len(title)
```